# Can i add health check exceptions for a classic load balancer in AWS ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

I want to add health check exceptions for 302 and 216 in aws classic loadbalancer health check of the target instances. can i do that? 
I can see there is a field to describe the http exceptions in ALB's but not in the classic LB's. Any clues? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are no exceptions in ELB Classic.

> If the load balancer receives any response other than `200 OK` within the response timeout period, the instance is considered unhealthy.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-healthchecks.html